# How to call submit.prevent on child component

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, vuejs2, vue-component

I've got a parent component with a submit button

```html
<v-card flat>
  <child-component :submit="submit()"></child-component>
  <v-card-actions>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-btn @click="submit" type="submit">Change password</v-btn>
  </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
```

and a child component with a form that has a @submit.prevent that I need to call whenever I click the button on the parent:

```html
<v-form @submit.prevent="submit">....</v-form>
```

My `submit()` is on the parent, it's just a simple function that submits the data to a database. It requires parameter `X`.
The reason I have a `@submit.prevent` on the child form is that I can press enter to submit the form.

How can I pass the `submit()` as a prop to the child? Or how can I call submit from the child component?

Answer (score 1):

The child should emit an event on submit:

```html
<v-form @submit.prevent="$emit('submit')">....</v-form>
```

And the parent can listen for that event to call the method:

```html
<child-component @submit="submit"></child-component>
```

Comment: For some reason the enter key is not submitting the form. I thought that could be fixed by putting a @submit.prevent... on the form in the child, in stead of calling the submit function only from the button. Any ideas why is that?

Comment: Since the `<v-form>` is in the child, the `<v-btn>` should be in there too. You could move the button from the parent or add a new one, but either way that's the easiest way for it to submit its `<v-form>`

Comment: And it fixes the issue with the enter key

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements)

```
      <v-card flat>
        <child-component ref="form"></child-component>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn @click="submit" type="submit">Change password</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>


 methods: {
        submit() {
          this.$refs.form.submit()
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use slots to pass your submit button from parent to child form and it will work. Also you can define default template, if no slots is passed. 
So you will be able to use form itself, without passed submit button (it will have it's own, default, button), or pass slot with  any button you need. 
Then you just listen to submit event of form (submit.prevent on form) and do whatever you want in parent component.

```js
Vue.component('form-component', {
  template: `
    <form @submit.prevent="submitEvent">
      <input type="text" v-model="value"/>
      <slot>
        <button type="submit"> Default Submit </button>
      </slot>
    </form>
  `,
  data: () => ({
    value: 'Hello Vue!'
  }),
  methods: {
    submitEvent(e) {
      this.$emit('submit', e);
    }
  }
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    submitForm(e) {
      console.log(e.target);
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form-component @submit="submitForm">
    <template v-slot>
      <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
    </template>
  </form-component>
</div>
```